# Different browsers have separate implementation of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I am referring to a page on JavaScript framework: [What is a JavaScript framework?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-jsframeworks/)

I know JavaScript is for the web client side. It is a object-oriented script language. The link above writes:

> Using JavaScript, however, is not an easy task, primarily due to the complications that arise when trying to provide support for multiple Web browsers.
>
> Like HTML and CSS, different browsers have separate implementations of JavaScript, and it can be a nightmare to ensure that your JavaScript code is cross-browser compatible.

The second part says different browsers has different implementations. Why?
Since JavaScript is just a language like Java, C etc. Why do different browsers need different implementations?

As long as the JavaScript language specification is released, each browser should follow the language requirement. So why they have different implementations?
What does the implementation here mean?

---

EDIT:

JavaScript is **NOT** a object-oriented language! It is a language based on objects!

Comment: It's "JavaScript" and "Java", by the way. I try not to be too pedantic, but you had quite a few variations on those. Using the correct names helps us make sure we know what you're referring to.

Comment: Historically, the problem is less the _language_ across browsers and more the DOM API.

Comment: It's not just for the web client side.  For example: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Javascript is not a nightmare to work with, by the way. Common usage can be simplified by using a library like jQuery, which handles many of the complications that might arise. A basic example is to look at the $.ajax method and compare it to the standard js routine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is an ECMA standard programming language and does not need to run in a browser. The browser has a JavaScript enginge that runs the script for you but not all browsers run it the same way.

Notabley is the way IE and other browsers handle events and new features are sometimes not supported. IE implemented things like innerHTML wich was not ECMA standard but because of it's popularity other browsers adopted it. It might be part of the standard now but I'm not sure.

The reason for this is that when NetScape came with JavaScript support IE implemented it as well but with other (extra) features. Since they both try to compete to be the "better" browser they didn't work together on making a standard.

A good source for JavaScript usage in browsers is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) It usually shows you browser support for JS methods and properties as well as some code to add some support for browsers that don't support certain features (like DOMParser parsing text/html)

In the last couple of years IE has made a move to be more ECMA complient so hopefully in the future we would have to rely on less and less feature detection in our JavaScript code.

You still have a problem that JavaScript is a still evolving language and more and more features are added. When they are new than browers will still implement it differently or not implement all featueres (like webcrt). You might also have to support browsers that are a couple of years old and a lot of things change in a couple of years.

Answer (score 3):

"Implementation" here is the engine that was implemented by a browser vendor according to [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) specification.

> As long as the java script language specification is released, each browser should follow the language requirement

And they do

> So why they have different implementations?

Because they follow the same specification but build their own engine.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way it is. Not every browser uses the same [JavaScript engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine), click the link if you want to read some interesting history.

They all try to be the fastest. And yes they should all follow the exact same specification, and I'm sure they have followed the exact same specification, but there are still people involved, and they might interpret the specification slightly differently.

These engines are being developed in parallel (at the same time), as none of their developers have time to wait for the others to develop something first, and then check to see if they can comply with the exact same interpretation of the specification as their competitors.